# How to render each vertex of graph smoothly step by step with a small delay (like animation)? Modern OpenGL

Tags: c++, animation, opengl, glsl, glfw

I am creating a small program for rendering trajectory path in real time. Entry data is array of vertex positions (x, y and z coordinates) and texture coordinates. When I compile the program it renders [the whole graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAgV0.png), I want to render it smoothly, like an animation, when every vertex (or pixel) appears with a small delay one by one. Is it possible?

I tried to make a delay in Vertex Shader like this

```
 #version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform float u_time;
uniform float u_deltaTime;

uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

float delay = 0.0;

void main()
{
if (delay < 5.0f)
    {
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * transform * vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0f);
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, 1.0f - aTexCoord.y);
    }
    delay = delay + u_deltaTime;
};
```

u_deltaTime is a uniform taken from while loop

```
 while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        float currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        GLint deltaTimeUni = glGetUniformLocation(graphShader.ID, "u_deltaTime");
        glUniform1f(deltaTimeUni, deltaTime);
       

        std::cout << lastFrame << "\t lastFrame\n";
     
        // -----
        glfwPollEvents();

        
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
        
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
      graphShader.use();
```

Here are my atrribPointers for this graph

```
 glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

Comment: you just render (in some timer or recuring event) using `glDrawElements` ... with variable size of the rendered data based on elapsed time ... no need to do anything in shaders for this....

Comment: Thank you so much! It works, I just feel myself dumb at this point, but yeah thanks!